# Jquery.How to detach/remove and stop an animation of a div with a <p> after the function is executed

Tags: jquery

I have a div with the ID `callus`, within that `div` I a link with a `paragraph(#call)`.
Now i have animated the `div` for the `hover` event, I have appended `Click=Free call` to that, so far so good.

However, the animation does not stop and i get repeated `Click=Free call` texts all the way to the footer.

And the animation does not stop on `mouseouleave`.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Regards

Here is the relevant part of the code:

My goal was to just have the appended text show up once.

```
$('#callus').hover(
  function() {
  $(this).animate({ width: "90%" }, 1000 )
  .animate({ height: "50px"},1000 )
  .animate({ fontSize: "24px" }, 1000 )
  .animate({ borderLeftWidth: "15px" }, 1000 );
  $('#call').append( "<p>Click=Free call</p>" );
  $('#call').mouseleave(
    function() {
      $('#call').detach( "<p>Click=Free call</p>");
    });
  });
```

Comment: Please read how to format your code. 
you should replace `); $('#call').mouseleave( function() {` by `, function() {` if using `.hover()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few notes:

1. You can enable code highlighting to make your code more readable by using the `{}` option in the toolar
2. You don't need to chain animate calls together to animate multiple properties, you can put them all in one call like below
3. `.stop()` will stop any animations on an object
4. Use `.text()` to change just the text of an element
5. Hover takes 2 callbacks. One for mouseenter, one for mouseleave. You have an additional mouseleave event inside your mouseenter event. Try calling `.hover()` like below
6. You don't animate your properties back in the mouseleave event FYI if that's what you wanted to do

See if any of the above changes fix your problem or try the code below.

```
$('#callus').hover(function() {
   $(this).stop().animate({
       width: "90%"
      ,height: "50px"
      ,fontSize: "24px"
      ,borderLeftWidth: "15px"
   });

   $('#call').text("Click = Free call"); 
},function() { 
   $('#call').text(""); 
});
```